# Unity: IPreprocessBuildWithReport is not running on Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am a new with Unity and I have been trying to build a Unity project where when it is built, it can also copy some files with the game.exe in the Build folder. For that, I need to understand how `IPreprocessBuildWithReport` works.

I have created a C# script called `MyCustomBuildProcessor.cs` and put it inside: `Assets\Scripts\Editor`  The script is as follows:

```
//Implement this function to receive a callback before the build is started.
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using UnityEngine;

class MyCustomBuildProcessor : IPreprocessBuildWithReport
{
    public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }
    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {
        Debug.Log("MyCustomBuildProcessor.OnPreprocessBuild for target " + report.summary.platform + " at path " + report.summary.outputPath);
    }
}
```

To my understanding, this script should run when I build the project, but the Log is not shown in the console. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

My build setting is as follows:
[Unity Build Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haeXH.png)  , [Unity Project Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBGqm.png)

My Unity version is: 2022.1.20f1

I have tried building in different version like 2021.3.10f1 and tried placing the file in outside the Editor folder but nothing has worked. Maybe there is something basic that I am missing. I am new to the Unity scene so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: doubt that this is the issue but have you tried making the class `public`?

Comment: @ghufran-ullah, Did you figure this issue out? I'm running into the same.

Comment: Yeah I did figure it out. Turns out it was running but the log were being cleared so I could not see the logs. What I did to verify is to create a .bat to see an output like the following:
```
@echo on
print %1
pause
```
and then I wrote the script to print some values and it was showing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just uncheck the "Clear on Recompile" toggle:

[image: Clear on Recompile]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was always running but the logs were being cleared so I could not see the logs. I created a bat file to copy files named "print-output.bat" as follows:

```
@echo on
print %1
pause
```

Then I wrote the script to show the log to the bat file and it worked. So it is actually working but just not showing in `Debug.Log()`.